# Angular test looking for function on stub

Tags: angular

I've written a test for a component, I added a stub of a service. Now I'm getting an error, I don't understand why I'm getting this error, I thought stubs were made to avoid having to use the original service, why is the tester looking for the onLoginChanges function?

```
TypeError: this.authService.onLoginChanges is not a function
```

**Test Spec**

```
describe('test A', () => {

    let comp: MainMenuComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MainMenuComponent>;
    let debugElementTitle: DebugElement;
    let elementTitle: HTMLElement;
    let authService: AuthService;

    beforeEach(() => {

        let authServiceStub = {
            isLoggedIn: true,
            onLoginChanges() {
                console.log('on login changes called from mock/stub');
            }
        };

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ MainMenuComponent ],
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: AuthService,
                    useValue: authServiceStub
                }
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainMenuComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        authService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AuthService);

        debugElementTitle = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#signin-link'));        
        elementTitle = debugElementTitle.nativeElement;
    });

});
```

Original class constructor:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService
            //private router: Router
            ) {

    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    let self = this;

    this.authService.onLoginChanges().subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.isLoggedIn = newValue;
    });
}
```

I updated the code to include useClass instead and included the onLoginChanges(), now I'm getting `'cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined...` referring to the subscribe in the service constructor. What is the injection process? does it go through the original class and make sure it has all the same properties and functions? Is there some sort of interface thing going on between the service and stub because of the provider in the module configuration? This is quiet confusing.

Comment: in your stub there is no onLoginChanges  function.also it would be better if you create a spy class for your service and then use useClass instead of useValue

Comment: I updated the code to include useClass instead and included the onLoginChanges(), now I'm getting 'cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined... what is the injector doing? does it go through the original class and make sure I've implemented it in the stub or something?

Comment: The code expects onLoginChanges() to return an Observable. Your fake onLoginChanges() method doesn't return anything. How can the code subscribe to nothing? The injector doesn't check anything. It just injects your fake service to the constructor, and the constructor calls it.

Comment: but the fake service doesn't even have a constructor

Comment: i'm a bit of newbie but if you elaborate more or give an answer :)

Comment: just curious is it the provider in the module config that make the code have to include all the properties and functions of the original authService component here?

Comment: did the below code work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
class AuthServiceStub {

    onLoginChanges= jasmine.createSpy('onLoginChanges').and.returnValue(
    Observable.of('some data here');
    );
}
```

Also add this to your provider array

```
{
                    provide: AuthService,
                    useClass: AuthServiceStub 
                }
```